Возможно ли покупать звёзды и премиум в телеграме с помощью aiogram?
Задался вопросом: можно ли пополнить счёт звёзд в Telegram или приобрести Telegram Premium через ботов? Очевидно, что существуют боты, которые позволяют это сделать. Однако, как разработчику на Python, мне всегда было интересно понять, как это работает "под капотом".
Я знаком с процессом оплаты в ботах с использованием карт или звёзд, но не могу разобраться, как именно реализовать покупку звёзд в Telegram-боте. Хотелось бы получить помощь от разработчиков, которые сталкивались с подобными задачами, или от людей, которые могут объяснить, как это устроено. Буду рад любым ответам и подсказкам!

https://github.com/dakri1/StarPayBot
Я тут принимаю оплату в stars и приглашаю пользователя вступить в приватный канал.
Надеюсь поможет. Будут вопросы по коду, задавайте. (Правда там есть refund_star_payment, оно возвращает обратно ту сумму, которую бот получил, эту строчку можно убрать)

Конечно, это немного не то, что мне нужно, но всё равно спасибо! Насколько я помню, звёзды можно приобрести через fragment.com, однако я пока не могу найти API и инструкцию по его использованию. Ещё раз спасибо за отклик, даже если он немного не по теме! ;)
